# Unable to locate the repository cloned from git using Azure cloud shell

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-cloud-shell

I opened Azure Cloud Shell and once the command prompt was ready, I tried git clone https://github.com/Azure-Samples/python-docs-hello-world and it was cloned successfully. However, i am unable to locate where the cloned files are. Need help with the process for locating using Azure Cloud Shell.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Cloud shell stores the files in a **file share** within a **storage account** that you either specified or Azure created for you.

> When you use basic settings and select only a subscription, Cloud
>   Shell creates three resources on your behalf in the supported region
>   that's nearest to you:

```
Resource group: cloud-shell-storage-<region> 
Storage account: cs<uniqueGuid> 
File share: cs-<user>-<domain>-com-<uniqueGuid>
```

[Source.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/persisting-shell-storage#how-bash-in-cloud-shell-storage-works)

Comment: I tried your instructions.. however I can't locate inside cloud drive the repository that I cloned from github. May be there is some gap  as explained here - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/a2dadd2f-4daa-44c4-8341-9a3f7a44eb58/cannot-clone-git-repo-into-azure-cloud-shell-clouddrive?forum=windowsazuremanagement